# Adding a custom email recipient depending on selected custom checkout field value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

I need for Woocommerce to send a custom email to different individuals depending on the option selected for Field Checkout (technically, the custom field is the person reporting on the product variant they have purchased, but I was not sure how to customize email receipt based on product variant purchased, so it is as follows).

First I established the custom field using the following code

```
/**
 * Add the field to the checkout
  */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('Membership') . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array('wps-drop'),
        'label'         => __('Membership purchased'),
        'options'       => array(
            'blank'     => __( 'Select membership ordered', 'wps' ),
            'premium'   => __( 'Premium Membership', 'wps' ),
            'gold'  => __( 'Gold Membership', 'wps' ),
            'silver'    => __( 'Silver Membership', 'wps' ),
            'bronze'    => __( 'Bronze Membership', 'wps' )
        )
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ));

    echo '</div>';

}

/**
 * Process the checkout
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['my_field_name'] =='blank')
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please select status.' ), 'error' );
}
```

Then I setup email receipts based on value selected:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'new_order_conditional_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
function new_order_conditional_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {

    // Get the order ID (retro compatible)
    $order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;

    // Get the custom field value (with the right $order_id)
    $my_field_name = get_post_meta($order_id, 'my_field_name', true);

    if ($my_field_name == "premium")
        $recipient .= ', emailreceipt1@gmail.com';
    elseif ($my_field_name == "gold")
        $recipient .= ', emailreceipt2@gmail.com';
    elseif ($my_field_name == "silver")
            $recipient .= ', emailreceipt1@gmail.com';
    elseif ($my_field_name == "bronze")
        $recipient .= ', emailreceipt2@gmail.com';

    return $recipient;
}
```

When I use this code though, none of the receipts who are supposed to receive their designated email actually do. What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just missed to save the selected custom field value in the order meta data. I have also revisited your code a bit:

```
// Add custom checkout field
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );
function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('Membership') . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array(
        'type'      => 'select',
        'class'     => array('wps-drop'),
        'label'     => __('Membership purchased'),
        'required'  => true, // Missing
        'options'   => array(
            ''          => __( 'Select membership ordered', 'wps' ),
            'premium'   => __( 'Premium Membership', 'wps' ),
            'gold'      => __( 'Gold Membership', 'wps' ),
            'silver'    => __( 'Silver Membership', 'wps' ),
            'bronze'    => __( 'Bronze Membership', 'wps' )
        )
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ) );
    echo '</div>';
}

// Process the checkout
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');
function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( empty( $_POST['my_field_name'] ) )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please select status.' ), 'error' );
}

// Save the custom checkout field in the order meta
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_field_checkout_update_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_field_checkout_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['my_field_name'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'my_field_name', $_POST['my_field_name'] );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order',  'new_order_conditional_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
function new_order_conditional_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    if( is_admin() ) return $recipient;

    // Get the order ID (Woocommerce retro compatibility)
    $order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;

    // Get the custom field value (with the right $order_id)
    $my_field_name = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'my_field_name', true );

    if ($my_field_name == "premium")
        $recipient .= ',emailreceipt1@gmail.com';
    elseif ($my_field_name == "gold")
        $recipient .= ',emailreceipt2@gmail.com';
    elseif ($my_field_name == "silver")
        $recipient .= ',emailreceipt1@gmail.com';
    elseif ($my_field_name == "bronze")
        $recipient .= ',emailreceipt2@gmail.com';

    return $recipient;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested in WooCommerce 3+ and works.

> As you will see **the recipient is correctly added** in "New Order" email notification depending on the customer choice.