# Woocommerce - adapt email recipient on order based on package's shipping method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Good afternoon everyone.

I've been struggling for a couple of days with the following issue :
I have a woocommerce cart divided in X packages. Based on the sipping option selected for a package A, I wish to send an email to an email adress B. Each shipping option having a linked email adress.
Now, my issue is : I've found the code part in woocommerce where the recipient is given to the system I believe : class-wc-email.php. When I have 3 packages, I receive 4 emails on the same email adress at the moment, one global, and one with the content of each package. So my idea is that in this file, I'd like to test the shipping method selected for each package (assuming that each package = one order), and based on this information, adapt the email adress.

Something like :

```
public function get_recipient() {


    if( $chosen_shipping == 'blabla' ){
        $recipients = "recipient@gmail.com";
    }
    else if( $chosen_shipping == 'blablabla' ){
        $recipients = "recipient2@gmail.com";
    }
    else {
        $recipient  = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_@recipient_' . $this->id, $this->recipient, $this->object, $this );
        $recipients = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $recipient ) );
        $recipients = array_filter( $recipients, 'is_email' );
        $recipients = implode( ', ', $recipients );
    }
    return $recipients;
}
```

This type of problem has been adressed in the past, for instance in this topic : [Woocommerce email notifications additional recipients based on user role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479815/woocommerce-email-notifications-additional-recipients-based-on-user-role)
However, suggested solutions are often depreciated and I can't figure out a way of making it work.

Thank you in advance for your time and help :)

Comment: Where do you call your function `get_recipient`?

Comment: Hello Mr Jo, this function is already made by woocommerce and is present in the woocommerce code. Above is a simple variation of how I would like to make it work. The original function is this one : https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_emailget_recipient/

However I do not know all the places where this function is called in all the wc hooks and files. I do not call it directly, but from what I've seen WC does during the order process.